# Photon: System.Collections.Hashtable vs ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I am working with Photon in Unity now, and in all tutotials I can see that people use `ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable` to set customRoomProperties. My question actually is: what are the difference between default C# Hashtable class and photon Hashtable class. And why I should use only Photon Hashtable to set my room properties, if they are both representing a KeyPairValue type?

Comment: Photon is expecting their hashtable as the collection type.  It is a different type, most likely they have a different implementation based on how they use it.

Comment: Have you tried to press `F12` on it -> yes it is a complete custom implementation! They use an underlying `Dictionary<object, object>` .. kind of dump tbh since they state themselves (and I tested) `string` is the only allowed type for the key ... All other keys are allowed but simply ignored when setting the properties ^^ ... And in general why should you use the Photon `Hashtable`? -> well the room `CustomProperties` and according setter method only uses the Photon `Hashtable` ... you can't just use another type on it that casually has the same name ;)

Comment: We had to come up with as solution since `System.Collections.Hashtable` was not available for UWP/WSA/NET_FX platform(s) in Unity. This "workaround" was kept for backward compatibility I think.